# How to select first tab by default in JS tabs?

Tags: javascript, tabs

I've used [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp) tutorial from w3schools to code javascript tabs for a tumblr theme(mostly because it's the only one I found that goes well with bullet lists) and while it works smoothly for most part, I can't seem to make my first tabs be selected by default.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
body {font-family: verdana;
}

/* Style the tab */
div.tabby {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding:0px;
    text-align:center;
}

/* Style the links inside the tab */
div.tabby button {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    text-shadow:none;
    color: white;
    background:#99b6f9;
    border-top: 4px double #f8dbdd;
    border-bottom: double 4px #f8dbdd;
    border-left: 4px double #f6c3cb;
    border-right: 4px double #f6c3cb;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size:15px;
    cursor:inherit;
    outline:none;
}

/* Change background color of links on hover */
div.tabby button:hover {
    font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
    background: #96cce8;
    color: white;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
div.tabby button.active {
    background: url('http://data.whicdn.com/images/222075536/large.jpg');
    outline:none;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabbycontent {
    display: none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
    animation: fadeEffect 1s;
}

/* Fade in tabs */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeEffect {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

<div class="tabby">
  <button class="tabbylinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tabbylinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tabbylinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabbycontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabbycontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabbycontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

    <script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, tabbycontent, tabbylinks;
    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    tabbycontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabbycontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabbycontent.length; i++) {
        tabbycontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    tabbylinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tabbylinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tabbylinks.length; i++) {
        tabbylinks[i].className = tabbylinks[i].className.replace("active", "");
    }
    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My first problem is that I utilize more than one single set of tabs, and they're all sorted in different links around my theme, so they don't function as one single tabs code. Second, while I've managed to make the first tab of the main set work, the code will reset previously clicked tabs of other sets to non active property and everything goes to stake zero. I don't know much of javascript but none of the solutions I found did really help my case, can anyone help a leaf out?

Comment: Are you looking for a different method than the one provided on the page you linked? It looks like the example they give works well with the way the tabs are set up.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for another method since the 'show a tab by default' code reset itself whenever I click on a tab from a set coded in a different link. Sorry if my words aren't that clear!